# Programming a macro to run automatically after installing an AddIn

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have an Add-In that will be shared among several users.

Inside that Add-In, I have a Macro called `displayParameters()`, which just registers the other functions from the Add-In, along with the description of those functions and their parameters.

**The problem is that everytime an user installs the Add-In, he/she has to run that macro once in order to register the functions/parameters.**

Is there a way I can **make the macro run automatically everytime an user install the Add-In?**

I do not want the macro to run everytime an user opens a spreadsheet with the add-in installed, or anything like that.

I want the macro to run only after installing the Add-In.

By installing the Add-In I mean going to `Developer -> Add-Ins -> Selecting the Add-In -> Ok`

Is there anything similar to Change Event but related to AddIns?

Answer (score 2):

In the ThisWorkbook code module of the add-in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    displayParameters
End Sub
```

Comment: [Useful reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822158.aspx)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.